# High-Functioning Autists as Space Colonists

Tags: space-colonization, psychology

In commentaries to my other question @JustinThyme suggested that [high-functioning autists could be the best space colonists](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/92432/39490):

> A great deal of very successful scientists ARE autistic. Einstein, for
>   instance, [showed autistic tendencies](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn3676-einstein-and-newton-showed-signs-of-autism/). Autistics have a very high
>   representation among surgeons. In fact, the best space colonists would
>   be from the autistic population. Most of the traits needed are
>   synonymous with autistic traits.

I think it is an intriguing idea, although, I am not sure it would work.

Even [high-functioning autists](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/High-functioning_autism) have emotional and social problems. They experience difficulties connecting with other people and maintaining relationships. They are also prone to developing anxieties.

I can see how a person with [Asperger syndrome](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Asperger_syndrome) could be helpful to a colony due to their amazing focusing ability (although, I am not sure that this focus is deliberate). But I am having a really hard time imaging how a group of people with high-functioning autism and/or Asperger syndrome could establish and maintain a functioning colony.

I wonder if social and emotional impairments typical for autism spectrum disorders could jeopardise the survival of a space colony. Or maybe they would actually benefit it.

***NB***: All colonists have normal or higher than normal intelligence. **All** colonists have autism spectrum disorders, but not necessarily Asperger syndrome.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but what is your question? Your entire post doesn't contain a single question mark.

Comment: Assuming your question is, "Would people with high-functioning autism make good space colonists?", you'll want to put that in the post. You may also want to edit in the information from the other question, regarding why pojo-guy believes they would.

Comment: "(although, I am not sure that this focus is deliberate). But I am having a really hard time imaging how a group of people with high-functioning autism and/or Asperger syndrome could establish and maintain a functioning colony." - it does not have to be a group 100% out of those people. There should be people which connect those in one functioning group. Which percentage is optimal is a question without theoretical answer, but if you wish it to be a plot just make it more than usual.

Comment: @MolbOrg, the premise was that all of them are on the autistic spectrum.

Comment: I believe the question is exactly the same as: Aren't people with Asperger syndrome better at everything? I don't see how this applies to space colonies specifically. Could you maybe specify what that colony would be like? A stereotypical sci-fi colony on some lush planet where people are basically the same as the American pioneers or an actual colony on a space rock (take Mars) with only scientific purpose? Should it become self-sustaining? Where do you think their focusing ability would be beneficial?

Comment: @Olga I understand that, it just not a realistic premise, and really a mix would be more efficient. But sure it is your Q and I see you incorporated 100% thing, so. Are those people artificially grown or are they selected from  a natural population?

Comment: Believe me, Aspergers are definitely not *better at everything*

Comment: In my opinion, autistic people would make terrible colonists which really require very close human relationships to thrive which is hard for autists.

Comment: Thank you for the credit, but I think the autism credit rightly belongs to @JustinThyme

Comment: @pojo-guy, my bad. Thank you very much for correcting me here. Although, it was the discussion between the two of you that made me ask this question.

Comment: @MolbOrg, I guess they are selected from the general population. No genetic alterations and such...

Comment: How is this question different from asking a question about how those with any other medical condition could function together as colonists? E.g. "How well could a Mars colony function if all of the colonists had diabetes?"

Comment: Autism is different from diabetes because some of the traits of that are considered on the autistic spectrum lend themselves to success in a survival situation. People with autism don't need medication to survive from day to day,  but they may have the ability to hyper focus, or be savants in their chosen field. A geologist  who is trans-sensory may pick up on fine details that normal folk need an electron microscope to see. An alexithymic will have no issues with long term separation from other people.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, while any chronic disease affects one's psychological state, conditions like autism create a drastically different social situation. High-functioning autism is associated with social and emotional patterns not normally found in people with diseases like diabetes. My question is not about managing autism but about building a community considering very specific psychological symptoms of autistic spectrum disorders (ASD). It is not possible to substitute ASD with diabetes or similar disease in this context.

Comment: Is high functioning austism an actual term? I thought it was just a another of Chris-chan's cwcisms.

Comment: @Recelica the term is used to describe individuals on the spectrum that are capable of handling day-to-day life mostly themselves without too big issues. E.g. they are able to grasp the nuances of interpersonal communication and manage to replicate things that others don't even need thinking about. Some even manage to cope and work with their own feelings instead of trying to block them out because they can play haywire with you.

Comment: @Recelicia in current art, the character Zane from the Ninjago animation series is a well executed example of high functioning autistic  with alexithymia.

Comment: Interesting question! I happen to be a high-functioning autist myself, so I'm very interested to see what people make of it!

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that High Functioning autists might not be great colonists, but would make great ships crew.

ASD (autism spectrum disorder) has a very wide variety of symptoms and it takes a combination of them to make a diagnoses.  That's why you need to screen heavily for the right combinations of symptoms.

Useful ones I can think of would be hyperfocus and moderate to mild sensory sensitivity.  Another common one that would be useful as ships crew is a tendency toward rigid adherence to rules.

1. **Hyperfocus**
   Even complex tasks, when performed repeatedly, will become boring for many that would be considered "Neurotypical".  Ship safety relies on observation of a wide variety of variables.  Someone on the spectrum might be able to shut out almost all of the outside world to focus on those variables, note changes and report them.  They can do things like this for long periods of time without going nuts.
2. **Sensory sensitivity**
   Have you ever known a car guy who will tell you that your car is about to break because your engine sounds wrong?  This is the kind of quality you want to look for.  Sensory sensitivity in more severe cases are why some on the spectrum will look away and turn an ear to you when you talk.  This isn't rude behavior, but they simply can't take in both audio input and sight input at the same time.  With milder cases and coupled with focus, someone who can shift focus to exclude sight may notice any machinery that is maybe not right, but it hasn't shown up on the readouts as normal.
3. **Rigid rule conformity**
   One of the things that has defined ships safety since groups of people went out on little piles of wood into the water has been for the crew to react as one to a variety of situations.  Get a small group of people who have a natural inclination towards following the rules, and most problems will be met rapidly, effectively, and without debate.

So those are some ways that High functioning people on the Spectrum would be a benefit to ships crew.  Here is why they may not make the greatest colonists.

**Rigid rule conformity** The ship is a small, consistent environment.  Not a lot of changes.  A Colony planet is going to need a lot of creative thinking, and maybe total re-evaluation of many of the rules and assumptions.  This is going to be very disorienting to someone on the spectrum.  Massive change is **extremely** hard for them.

Likewise with **Focus and sensory sensitivities.**  Get too wrapped up in hearing Alien Bird Song might mean you miss the deadly green bug crawling on your pant leg.

**Edit:**  This generally assumes the Sci-Fi trope of colonists landing on another planet and setting up shop right out there on the land in shelters and log houses on the prairie. It was pointed out that this is not exactly a realistic scenario.  It still stands though that the kind of challenges of a planet side  colony are still going to be a very challenging change scenario for people on the Autism Spectrum.  The reasons for establishing a colony are varied, but they generally involve establishing a beach head of sorts and then expanding.  This means EVA's, dealing with the local landscape, and possibly dealing with local flora and fauna.  This means a lot of change from routine and chaos even in a sealed environment.  It could possibly be too much to adapt to in a short time frame.

Comment: In what way would a colony on a planet not be a small, consistent environment? Wouldn't it be basically be a small space station on the ground of some planet? Not suggesting they would be great for the job, I'm just confused by the argumentation

Comment: I'm thinking of pioneers, huts on the ground, going out and exploring kind of colonization.  Just after they found out the air was breathable on Earth 2 kind of thing.  That seem sto me to be a  typical colonization pattern through history:  Get there and spread out

Comment: This is a well established concept in Scifi, but the chances we will ever find a planet in which humans can live out on the open are 0%. And I mean exactly 0%. The only way would be some kind of terraforming and in that case we will not have "people in the wild" but people at Disneyland. I'm not saying this is a wrong assumption because it might very well be what this question is about, I think you should edit in that you are answering under the assumption that x, y and z - for example to make it more clear what you are talking about

Comment: @Raditz_35 Fair enough

Comment: @Raditz_35, in a way I am a proxy here. I was given a suggestion and I am trying to wrap my mind around it. I am trying to figure out a situation where the suggested group would work out. Thus, I was hoping people would suggest a colony type where autistic disorder would be beneficial.

Comment: @Olga you might want to narrow your question,  since ASD covers so much range, including behaviors that were considered odd but within the range of normal when I was a kid . Are you looking for a group of hyper focusers with an alexithymic to keep them on task? A trans sensory engineer (that ventilator sounds chartreuse so it needs a new fan belt)? What are the characteristics that your colony needs?

Comment: @Vylix, thanks for the Edit!  looks better than mine

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that selecting colonists because they are on the autism spectrum is necessarily wise.

ASD covers a very broad range. Typically, I would expect you to select for a range of capabilities based on the roles to be performed. Some people on the ASD spectrum might fit into specific niches required by your community, but I would never expect the autism to be a deciding factor in and of itself.

For example, I have a graphics artist on my webcast team. The requirements of the role are:

- good aesthetic sense,
- ability to focus and do creative work in real time in a chaotic environment,
- finds satisfaction in a role where he is relatively isolated from the rest of the team, and
- ability to use some specific software packages.

I found the perfect match, and found out much later by accident that he is autistic.

His autism is a benefit in that role because a part of his condition is being synesthetic. He experiences emotions and sensations as colors, so he is finely attuned to subtleties of art that I completely miss.

He and I get along well in part because I am oblivious to many social signals, so I don't pick up on his behaviors that drive neurologically normal folks nuts. However, If I were neurologically normal, his social skills would be a sufficient liability to rule him out, no matter how good he is technically.

Comment: "He experiences emotions and sensations as colors" - I believe the technical term for that is "synesthesia".

Answer (score 4):

My grandson is autistic, through him I know a dozen other autistic children.

A major problem with autistic children is a failure to understand the needs of other people, the pain of other people, the wants of other people. They don't care because in a way they are incapable of it; they do not have the normal structures that let them feel sympathy or empathy with another. Other people can be objects to them, objects that cry when pushed, but it's like turning on the TV or radio and hearing a car engine or a speech: To them, no emotional impact from the crying, they pushed an object out of their way and that was the end of that.

This is not to say they do not have their OWN emotions; they cry, feel pain, and get angry when they don't get their way. They just have a lot of failure understanding that OTHER people have emotions, or don't relate to them well: Once my grandson asked his mother, "Are you mad?" She said, "Yes, I am very mad." He replied, "Stop being mad. I don't like it!"

Autistic people would not be good colonists. They can't be good supervisors because they don't understand other people, or how problems affect other people. On their own, if they are constrained and disciplined (without harming them) they can get jobs done. But they DO have their own emotions, wants, hurts and favorites, you cannot just program them like robots.

They may not feel a need for the **companionship** of other people, but they do still **need** other people. On their own in the wild, they would die: Humans are weak, slow, and easy prey even when fully abled. As colonists, you would have a hundred people on their own, not a team of a hundred people. They don't naturally form teams, they can only be part of one if somebody else is running the show.

Autistics (or Aspbergers) are ***not*** smarter than everybody else when it comes to social glue and relationships and working together toward a shared goal, that is a defining characteristic of being autistic. If they had that, even in normal measure, they wouldn't be autistic, they'd just get labeled as having an OCD or compulsion or anxiety.

Comment: Your description is that of sociopathy, not autism. Autistic people feel sympathy and empathy for other individuals, often more intensely than normal people, they have difficult picking up on the social cues and body language that indicate distress. A common behavior for autistic people is overlooking distress by accident, having the sympathetic emotional distress hit 100 fold when it actually dawns on them what happened, then beating themselves up that they failed to pick up on the pain of someone they cared about. **Sociopaths** see people as objects.

Comment: I have to agree; I have autism, I'm high functioning, and I can sympathize and even empathize. I just have difficulty understanding the many intricacies of social cues; otherwise, I'm very conscientious and polite, which is the exact _opposite_ of sociopathy. No judgment though; plenty of people misunderstand autism.

Comment: An interesting point is that a lot of autistic people have difficulty recognising their *own* emotions, or at least understanding what they're feeling and what's provoking it enough to do anything sensible about it.  Their response may be to just ignore their feelings completely unless they get so overwhelmed that they can't hold it together any more and have a screaming meltdown (in which they may still be unclear about exactly what's bothering them, only that they feel awful).  The technical term is "alexithymia".

Answer (score 3):

No offence intended, but extremes of any sort will be bred into the population and eventually show physically, psychologically and politically. For colonists you are much better off with a wider spectrum of people.

Comment: A problem that might arise is that in the offspring of the high-functioning colonists one gene will meet another to lead to a large proportion of children who happen to have inherited a double dose and are *severely*, cripplingly autistic.  I'd imagine that would be murder to deal with in a struggling space colony, though at least everyone will be familiar with the idea and know what they're up against.

Answer (score 3):

My first response to all the responses is ... are any of you autistic?  If not, you are not really qualified to provide any reasonable description of what being autistic/aspergers means.  First, the diversity of "issues" that the autistic population deal with is huge.  One experience with one autistic person is merely one data point.  It borders on irresponsibility to then generalize the entire autistic population based on that single experience.

The neurodiverse people are classic hunter/gatherers (rather than having an agrarian based environmental response).  They are your classic explorers/scouts.  They should always be part of the leading edge of any exploration.  They are problem solvers that interpret their environment in unique ways that neurotypicals do not.

Certainly, not all autists would be qualified.  We are not all qualified to be astronauts, are we?  There would be a selection process that would choose those who thrive in new and challenging environments.  Someone, like Charles Darwin, a typical type asperger fellow who voyaged around the planet cataloguing life forms, would not be amiss.

Merely because autists are generally espoused to have low social IQs is not a huge factor.  I mean, they are a bit like computers aren't they, lacking in the banal give and take on inconsequential subjects?  I'm not sure why being socially adept is a high priority for space exploration.  In fact, all that neurotypical emotion just gets in the way of getting the job done.  Think about the mind set of the military and NASA personnel....

Comment: This. All of these answers sound like neurotypical people talking *about* autism from an external point of view, rather than people who actually know how autistic people think. Most of the answers are autism stereotypes (e.g. autistics as sociopaths) rather than understanding why they behave this way and how they would react in such a situation. Look at how most of the answers start with "My x has autism and..."

Comment: Welcome to the site D.Boone. You will discover a perhaps atypically high number of those on the spectrum participating on the SE network, this includes those as yet undiagnosed. You'll also find others from all walks of life including well qualified medical practitioners, geologists, physicists, several authors, actors ... I could go on. You are most welcome here. Enjoy the site.

Comment: such a rush in judgment, but Tantalus pointed that out already. ops premise clearly isn't well-thought through, no matter which angle one takes. "I mean, they are a bit like computers aren't they" - nop, they are complex human-based systems, as anyone else, practically it means they can go haywire at any time like any other meatbag. Meatbags have to form a system capable to reach objectives, and resistant to a possible variety of external stimuli aka situations. To improve u answer u need to focus on ops q, is it beneficial or not, care less about answers of others. they are just digits.

Comment: As Molb indicates, this is not a place for criticizing other's answers. Any issue with an answer should be commented on as a comment on that specific answer not in an answer in itself. I think you would find it beneficial to take the time to study the [help], as well as a variety of successful questions (say, those with 20 + up-votes) and see the standard of answers that appear there. You will realize that we rely on answers substantiated by facts, more than emotional responses or opinions.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone here is missing a much broader issue that would make a colony of space autistics a bad idea. [Autism is characterized by a lack of motor coordination](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5996852/#:%7E:text=Children%20with%20autism%20not%20only,skills%20hamper%20participation%20with%20peers.), all people with autism either have poor gross motor skills or lack fine motor dexterity which results in terrible hand-eye coordination. Autistic people can't accurately do things like catch a ball to save their life, and most who excel in physical activities like martial arts only do so after extensive training to compensate. This would be bad in space where failing to have good hand-eye coordination could result in small debris clogging the air filters or failing to grab something in an EVA.

Also, autistic people usually don't get along well with other autistic people. It's not like autistic people are all on some alien wavelength that lets them vibe together. Indeed, from an autistic perspective the neurotypicals come off as kind of a hive mind. They wouldn't cooperate well.

Then there's the issue that while heritable we don't know what actually causes autism. You would have some inheritance of autism but you would have issues where many children born are either neurotypical or have low-functioning autism (non-verbal, unable to communicate at all, etc.), which is really bad.

Comment: out of recent necroposting, this is a good one.

Comment: Oh, good catch.  Everyone has been talking about the psychological traits, but that one is important.  I'm not sure that it's as universal as you describe it, but it would certainly be a problem the majority of candidates would show.

Comment: @A.B. The studies I've read suggest it seems pretty universal, and is actually one of the indirect criteria doctora will use when making an autism diagnosis. It's so pronounced you can even tell autistic people apart from neurotypicals by the way they walk because they are compensating for less body coordination.

Comment: It's a long time since I've read up on it so you may be right.  Interesting idea in that paper you referenced about the balance issues possibly being the cause of some of the anxiety issues.  I've sometimes thought that myself (it's certainly how *I* feel when my co-ordination is worse than usual) and it's interesting that the scientists thought so too, having looked at more people.

Comment: While interesting, it also continuously puts questionmarks if this is a symptom or a cause. If a symptom then the conclusion clarifies that the lack of motor coordination can be avoided: Because the ASD children are afraid of the social interactions they avoid interactions like sports, which hinders their learning of motor skills and causes their apparent drop. Since the people you are sending will likely be growing up in an environment designed for autists they will be able to learn these skills, which in my experience is true.

Comment: @Demigan Other studies suggest it is definitely a symptom that seems to have some neurological basis (deficient proprioception and overdevelopment of sensory abilities leading to poor balance and coordination). It shows up in activities that have nothing to do with social skills like walking or standing on one foot with your eyes closed. Autistic reflexes are terrible, and while its possible to compensate for them most people still end up below average.

Comment: @user2352714 That's my point: Social activities and the skills of walking and standing are linked. If you aren't interested or even afraid of the social commitments, you'll avoid physical excersise from an earlier age and don't develop the physical skills.

Comment: @Demigan Walking is not socially linked. Even the most socially isolated hermit or basement-dwelling NEET has to stand and walk from place to place in order to survive. Autistic people have a slower, more cautious walk cycle because their sense of balance is messed up and if they try to walk "normally" they're liable to trip and fall. Most autistic people describe themselves as clumsy or ponderous regardless of their social skills.

Comment: @user2352714 Hi, I'm a normal-functioning autist who's been forced to doing a job where I walk and cycle for some time now. I walk faster than anyone else and carry more weight on my bike than anyone else. Before that I was also challenged to move a lot. The difference here is the amount of time I have spend moving. A socially isolated hermit might have to move, but he doesn't need to move much at all. And as with everything biological: If you don't use it, you lose it. A temporary brace that limits your arms already has a profound effect on coordination on healthy people.

Comment: @Demigan Am also an autist. Have always noticed huge problems with hand-eye coordination and coordination. Even though I participated in gymnastics and played sports as a child hand-eye coordination never improved. Always had a slower reaction time than everyone else around me and can't catch an object worth a darn. Thought I was just clumsy until I did more research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119399/discussion-between-demigan-and-user2352714).

Answer (score 2):

Autism is a spectrum, just like "normal" humans are on a different spectrum of intelligence and capabilities on all fronts. This means that not all high-functioning autists actually have a complete lack of social capabilities. Autists can learn social interactions. In fact female autists are so bombarded with so many social cues that the normal-functioning female autists are much more rarely found than the male ones.

Most people on the internet seem to think that all Autists are the classical "overload them and they start screaming" type, even though the screaming is just one (bad) coping mechanism for overload and there are many more. So let's just describe a scene that by all accounts should be nightmare-fuel for autists:

A 3-day large organized party with 6000+ people paying for entry and several tents blasting loud music. The people show all emotions from sadness, love, happiness, jealousy etc mutated by the various amounts of alcohol, drugs, sleep and food they had. At any one point several dozen conversations are taking place over the music while each person is bombarding everyone around them with a variety of bodylanguage and facial expressions.

Not only did a normal-functioning autist help during these parties several times a year while listening to the music, but he simultaneously worked there as a manager to make sure his part of the party ran smoothly so people showed up and were relieved in time while pitching in when it was busy. Each of these individually can be a cause to overload an autist, but this autist did all of these simultaneously without problems or overload. He was specifically requested for the job several times afterwards even.

Put that same autist with the right person in a silent and bare room, and you can overload him in 15 minutes flat.

The point: Not every autist is the same, and you aren't sending your autists to a clustered chaotic loud party but a structured space-colony. Even better: All others are also autistic and they are both trained and selected for the job!

You hold all the cards: The Autists are likely selected young and trained for the job for years. Just like not all "normal" humans can become an astronaut and need to be selected and trained for the job. You'll teach them coping mechanisms and test their capability to handle the stresses of the environment. What's even better is that our current society isn't build to deal with autists which never helped and only exacerbated the problem. Autists often find that they have to adapt to the people around them but at the same time the people around them make no effort to adapt to the autists (in fact some will deliberately be worse, trying to blame someone for attempted murder and almost winning the case worse). But your society is quite literally build out of Autists and can be build from the ground up to cater to them.

An advantage autists have is that they don't need that much space for their lives. They don't need as much space for relaxation, in fact many autists will relax or de-stress to avoid overload by specifically doing small tasks and making sure their environment is in perfect order. That is exactly what you want.

If you select your high-functioning autists you could very well end up with a lot of Einsteinian brainiacs in your colony. I actually don't doubt that it would be the most ordered, crime-free community ever to have existed.

Answer (score 1):

High functioning autistic people would be good for the day to day running. They live for routine so boredom and repetition wouldn't be an issue but they would be terrible as colonists because they are bad at adaption and change.

My brother has high functioning autism and works as an IT sys admin. He can handle the day to day running and problems he has seen before but he goes to pieces when facing a problem he doesn't know how to solve. Lucky for him he has an encyclopaedic memory for computers and networking.

Colonizing space has things go wrong and you have to be extremely adaptive to solve the issue. Failure to do so could end in death. They could quite easily freak out when faced with life and death choices.

At best you might have a couple for their fantastic, almost computer like minds but they could never be in charge.

Answer (score -2):

**NO This is Madness**

I'm going to simplify your fundamental problem.

A colony is like any other human communal or organizational structure:

**IT NEEDS UNIQUENESS AND INDIVIDUALITY**

Throughout history whenever man has attempted to homogenize a society it has resulted in failure. Forcing everyone to be this or think that inevitably gets crushed by the "out of the box" thinker that turns the table. In this case your collective of autists would be hammered by a normally composited society of socialites and autists.

**Normally**

I would try and explain my point further listing facts however you have now broached the incredibly enormous topic of what makes a society as well as human social patterns. There are plenty of text books, courses, and thesis you can read to enhance your understanding on this subject.

Suffice it to say, what happens when your incredibly focused autist astronaut encounters a problem outside his comfort zone. Autists are generally not known for their adaptability. No one wants their nuclear core technician rocking back and forwards against a wall while the siren are blaring.

Comment: Autism is wildly variable - we're not all the type you describe in your last paragraph - so it wouldn't be quite so bad.  But you're right that monocultures are always a problem, no matter what they're a monoculture of.  Maybe a better model would be a colony with some of each but a much higher proportion of autists than the standard 1%-or-thereabouts.  You'd have various shades of autists to handle jobs they're better at, neurotypicals to handle jobs all the autists are bad at, and with so many, you'd avoid all the problems caused purely by people not being familiar with autism.